# Nested Case When with Cast and SUM

Tags: sql, excel, nested, case-when

I am querying an ODBC through EXCEL and i have managed to get my statement to a certain stage but i am looking to take it a step further. This is because i found that if it is approved it is also considered as pending. So i put together the below statement but it keeps kicking back. Is there a better way i should be nesting this SUM CAST CASE WHEN statement as i will need to repeat this again but instead of doing a count up i will be looking to SUM the revenue which i currently only have in one big bucket.

```
SELECT 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName
, SUM(CASE WHEN CAST( InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciInvoiceApproved as INT) IS 1 THEN 1) AS 'Approved' 
    ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditID IS NULL THEN 1 ) AS 'Prepared'
    ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS 'Pending'
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate
, SUM(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciTotalNettValue) As 'Total Nett Value'
, SUM(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciVatValue) AS 'VAT Value'


FROM

SBS.PUB.Company Company_0
, SBS.PUB.InvoiceCreditItem InvoiceCreditItem_0

WHERE

InvoiceCreditItem_0.CompanyID = Company_0.CompanyID
AND (Company_0.CoaCompanyName<>'ATOS')
AND InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate >= ?

GROUP BY 

Company_0.CoaCompanyName
, InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciCreatedDate
```

What i currently see is:

```
Approved Prepared Pending
1         0           1
1         0           3
0         1           0
1         1           0
```

What i want to see

```
Approved Prepared Pending
    1         0           0
    1         0           2
    0         1           0
    1         1           0
```

The next stage i am looking at doing is:

```
CASE WHEN InvoiceCreditItem_0.InvoiceCreditID IS NULL THEN SUM(InvoiceCreditItem_0.IciTotalNettValue) END) AS 'Prepared Value'
```

Which i expect to show:

```
Approved Prepared Pending 
0          1000     0
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic you want to implement and a proper database tag would all help.

Comment: Gordon i have now edited to five you more of a visual as to what im looking at seeing i believe the ODBC is connected to a progress database v10